# string guess game using input from system

Tags: c++

I was solving a [string guess](http://codeforces.com/contest/753/problem/B),I had never solved this kind of problem earlier ,here
we have to query from the system and it will answer us and we have to guess the string based on that ,But I am little confused with the solution  below.
Here we are allowed to atmost 50 queries ,Is query means here number of times
we are looping over cout

Like here we are using cout 10 times in first loop + in next loop 
will these be counted as total number of queries

> My doubt

1) What do you mean by query here how it is being counted(like above I m not sure)?

2)Logic used to solve below problem

Please help I faced this kind of ques first time in my life

Please it will be really helpful if you can tell me with what logic

author is guessing string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<int> v;
int i,x,y;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    cout<<i<<i<<i<<i<<endl;
    flush(cout);
    cin>>x>>y;
    if(x || y){
        v.push_back(i);
    }
}
do{
    cout<<v[0]<<v[1]<<v[2]<<v[3]<<endl;
    flush(cout);
    cin>>x>>y;
    if(x==4){
        break;
    }
}while(next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: ***really helpful if you can tell me with what logic*** You could use an ide with debugger like Visual Studio to step through the code 1 line at a time looking at the variables at each step. With that said I would not call this good code.

Comment: There are no strings in your program, so, it fails to implement the requirements.

Comment: ***What do you mean by query here how it is being counted(like above I m not sure)?*** Its not being counted with this code. You may have to ask whomever gave you the assignment / qustion about that.

Comment: That's how I always do but problem is weird can you give me idea about my doubts

Comment: Please read the link then ask @drescherjm

Comment: if it was possible the why I would have been here @drescherjm

Comment: A note about the nature of Stack Overflow: The goal is to create a repository of question and answers to software problems that can be used by future programmers. In order to meet that goal a question must directly contain everything necessary to understand the question today, tomorrow and years from now. Links can't do that. They rot. Even if the link is still live, the content at the page may change.  Do not ask people to read the link. Reproduce the necessary information from the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a general idea

First figure out how to create four unique digits, one way to do that would be to create an array of all digits 0..9 then shuffle the array and take the first four digits from the array. That is your correct answer.

In order to let to read from the user, use std::cin and read into an array.

Now you need a way to evaluate what the user (or program) entered. 
First compare position and value between the two arrays (bulls), then
calculate the rest that is numbers that are in both arrays but in different
positions

```
using Digits = std::array<int, 4>;
auto evaluateGuess(const Digits& correct, const Digits& guess) -> size_t
{
  if (guess == correct)
  {
    std::cout << "congrats!" << std::endl;
    return correct.size();
  }

  size_t bulls{0};
  size_t cows{0};

  for (size_t i = 0; i != guess.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (guess[i] == correct[i])
    {
      ++bulls;
    }
    else
    {
      for (size_t j = 0; j != correct.size(); ++j)
      {
        if (guess[i] == correct[j]) // && i!=j but already handled above
        {
          ++cows;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  std::cout << "bulls: " << bulls << " cows:" << cows << std::endl;

  return bulls;
}
```